# Blog post contains a link to a deleted user

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, blog

[This blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) contains a broken link:

> [image]

This user no longer exists, network wide - guess it's pointless to remove his name now from the blog post, but think the name should not be a link, as it's just broken.

Comment: Whoever is voting to close this as "does not appear to seek input and discussion", I fail to see the logic in that sentiment.

Comment: @TinyGiant trolls are everywhere...

Comment: [The internet backs up your theory.](http://www.troll.me/images/toy-story-everywhere/trolls-trolls-everywhere.jpg)

Comment: That link to Trapp's account is *a trap*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - I've removed the link to his name.

Comment: umm... two and half years. Forgot I asked this. lol.